# Sorting on DynamoDB data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What is the best way to retrieve all my data from DynamoDB sorted by an attribute(that its not indexed on)?

Would indexing on that attribute help in obtaining all the records sorted?

If I choose to back it with ElasticSearch, can I do a scan to fetch all records from ElasticSearch sorted on the attribute I want?

Comment: Yes and yes, as you probably expected.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which SDk you are using but example in javascript you can do a scan and after it returns the data you can sort it